# Onclick buttons which are in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create different hyperlinks for 3 buttons when they are clicked in HTML.
I have looked around and there is a lot of examples which use JavaScript to do this - would this be better? why? I only want the buttons to load a different webpage. Thanks

Current HTML code for 3 buttons:

```
<div id="buttons">
        <button class="btn">Entry forms</button>
        <button class="btn">Scoresheets</button>
        <button class="btn">Results</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So add click handler and change the page's location. OR make them links.

Comment: Agreed. Make them links and style them.

Comment: @ArtOfCode what would this look like? The 3 buttons use CSS.

Comment: [**Buttons are not links**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)...if you want a link..use one and **style** it like a button

Comment: @CharleyBaker answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this the easy way or the hard way.

#### Easy way

Make them links. Give the links `href` attributes. Your work here is done. You could even style them to look like buttons if you like - but links work cross-browser, in any version, with or without JS.

```
<a href="yourpage.html" class="btn">Entry forms</a>
```

Here's a demo:

```css
.btn {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
        background: gray;
        background: linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240), rgb(200,200,200));
        border: 1px solid gray;
        border-radius: 3px;
        color: black;
    }
```

```html
<a href="yourpage.html" class="btn">Entry forms</a>
```

#### Hard way

Either `onclick` attributes:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="location.href='yourpage.html'">Entry forms</button>
```

Or add listeners dynamically:

```
document.getElementById("my-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    location.href = 'yourpage.html';
});
```

Comment: "Make them links. " - Exactly...+1

Comment: <button class="btn" onclick="location.href='yourpage.html'">Entry forms</button>

Comment: It works, but as @Paulie_D says, **[buttons are not links](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)**

Answer (score 0):

How about this for a quick and easy solution?

```
<div id="buttons">
        <button class="btn" onclick="location.href='xxx.html';">Entry forms</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="location.href='yyy.html';">Scoresheets</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="location.href='zzz.html';">Results</button>
</div>
```

As for your question about what's better and right - it depends on what you need to achieve upon clicking on the buttons. If you need some more complicated and long code to run when clicking a button, it would be better (and more understandable and manageable) to do it with a function that is called from the click and runs the code.

For example:

HTML:

```
<button id="my_button" class="..." value="..." />
```

Code:

```
jQuery("BUTTON#my_button").click(function(){
// run some code here...
});
```

I hope this answers your questions...

Comment: `javascript:` is unnecessary in `onclick` handlers

Comment: I'm not the downvoter -  I was making the observation.

Comment: Oh... sorry about that. I just don't understand why would someone vote my answer in minus like that. I also don't understand why my answer wasn't selected as THE answer for the question, as I have basically wrote the same thing as the answer that did get selected...
NM, thanks for your input here and have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<script>
    $('#buttons .btn').click(function(){

    var locHref = '';
        switch($(this).index()){
            case 0:
                locHref = 'EntryForms.com';
            break;
            case 1:
                locHref = 'ScoreSheets.com';
            break;
            case 2:
                locHref = 'Results.com';
            break;
        }
        location.href = locHref;
    });
</script>
```